# Set UIBarButtonItem is not animated with iOS11

Tags: uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, ios11, swift4, xcode9

This code worked fine before I upgraded to **Swift 4** and **iOS11** now the `UIBarButtonItem` is set but is not animated.

```
func setDeleteItem() {
    deleteItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .trash,
                                       target: self,
                                       action: nil)
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([deleteItem], animated: true)
}
```

Tested with a real device and simulator with the same result.

Is it a bug?

Comment: This definitely seems like a bug. File a radar.

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: @RoiMulia Not yet, the issue still persists in iOS 11.1.2

Comment: Ah, seems like we need to workaround it some how